# How do I rerender a react component in Meteor?react component.forceUpdate error in Meteor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, this, meteor-react

I am making a login form using Meteor 1.4 and react 15. My aim is to redirect user after login. Currently when user is logged in, the page does not redirect. However, You can no longer access login or register pages when logged in which is expected.

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

export default class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.forceUpdate = this.forceUpdate.bind(this)
    }
    onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let el = $(e.target);

        let email = el.find('#email').val();
        let password = el.find('#password').val();
        let confirmPassword = el.find('#confirmPassword').val();
        // Login user
        Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function(err){
            if(err){
                alert(err.reason);
            } else {
                //if logged in
                alert('Successfully logged in');
                this.forceUpdate();
            }
        });
    }
    render() {
        //if user is logged in => this part works!
        if(Meteor.user()){
            return <Redirect to='/' />;
        }else 
        return (
        <LoginForm />
        ) 
    }
}
```

The login code works, the only issue is I want the component to rerender when form is submitted, i can only do that using forceUpdate which spits out this error:
The routing is in react router 4 and not meteor's Flow-router

```
Exception in delivering result of invoking 'login': TypeError: this.forceUpdate is not a function
```

Comment: why don't u redirect after a login process. And *forceUpdate* was never declared in within class.

Comment: The only way i can redirect using rr4 is after rerendering. What do you mean forceupdate was never declared?

Comment: Your class doesn't is not complete from your question sample code. And i can't find `forceUpdate` within the class. That's y you receive this error. 

`Exception in delivering result of invoking 'login': TypeError: this.forceUpdate is not a function`

Comment: [forceUpdate is a react function.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate)

Comment: `this.forceUpdate()` should be avoided in many cases, but if you still want to use it remove this `this.forceUpdate = this.forceUpdate.bind(this);` within your constructor function.

Answer (score 1):

Just use 'state' for this scenario.
Use `this.setState({loggedIn: true})` on success and use state inside the render.

```
render(){

     this.state.loggedIn;

     if(Meteor.user()){
         return <Redirect to='/' />;
     } else {
         return (
            <LoginForm />
         ) 
     }
 }
```

Note: Currently you are not using the ES6 way to declare function i.e. you're using

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function(err){....})
```

instead of

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, (err) => {....})
```

Arrow function refers to parent's `this` instead of current scope's.

Comment: It doest help putting setState inside render as I only need to render once user has logged in. Also putting setState inside the onSubmit method throws this error
```Exception in delivering result of invoking 'login': TypeError: this.setState is not a function
```
this, even when storing this in a different variable to capture the parent context

Comment: Looks like you haven't binded `this` while calling onSubmit....
Please let me know how you're calling the function onSubmit. Could you paste the login component?

Comment: onSubmit function gets called as expected. Using state helped. But some other issues with Meteor.user() creeping up.
I guess the problem was about correctly binding and the this keyword.I had to do this:
```  componentDidMount(){
    //save the component context to avoid scope issues
    thisComponent = this;
  }
```
to get the correct context when working with state.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

let thisComponent;

export default class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {loggedIn: Meteor.user() !== null}// false if no user is logged in
   //save the component context to avoid scope issues
   thisComponent = this;

   }
  onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let el = $(e.target);

    let email = el.find('#email').val();
    let password = el.find('#password').val();
    let confirmPassword = el.find('#confirmPassword').val();
    // Login user
    Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, err => {
      if(err){
        Materialize.toast(err.reason, 4000);
      }else {
        Materialize.toast('Success loging in', 4000);
        //change state just to cause a rerender
        thisComponent.setState({ loggedIn: true })
       }
    });
  }

  render() {
    //if user is logged in
    if(Meteor.user()){
     return <Redirect to='/dashboard' />;
    }else 
      return (
        <LoginComponent />
     }
  }
```

Did that and the form does rerender, hence problem solved. but the state doesnt seem to change as expected. Meteor.user() seems to delay data.

Comment: Now I am following this with meteor specific [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43593096/meteor-user-and-localstorage-getitemmeteor-userid-return-null).